# Unit test the web api controller errors while reading file path from the config file as well response type

Tags: c#, nunit, asp.net-web-api2

Hi I am creating a web api controller which reads a path of the file from the web.config and then uses open xml sdk to read and load the excel document. I need to write a Nunit test to test this controller for the response.

I am basically having two problems and both are related

**Problem 1**

Since my Nunit is in the class librabry project it cant read the value from the config settings and errors out. How do I handle this in my test for the controller.

It errors out at this line of the code in the Nunit test method

```
_response = customerController.GetCustomer();
```

**Problem 2**

The same line of code i.e    _response = customerController.GetCustomer(); also errors out because it returns type viewmodel and not response. How do I test the response object. Or do I need to test the view model object. Any insights would be helpful

**WebApi Controller method**

```
public IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> GetCustomer()
{
    string relativePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath"];
    return (OpenSpreadsheetDocument(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, relativePath)));
}
```

**Nunit test method**

```
[Test]
public void GetCustomerTest()
{
    var customerController = new CustomerController()
    {
        Request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri(ServiceBaseURL + "api/getcustomer")
        }
    };
    customerController.Request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey, new HttpConfiguration());

    _response = customerController.GetCustomer();

    var responseResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CustomerViewModel>>(_response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    Assert.AreEqual(_response.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.OK);
    Assert.AreEqual(responseResult.Any(), true);

}
```

Based on suggestion

**Updated WebAPI method**

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage  GetCustomer()
{
    string relativePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath"];
    IEnumerable  <CustomerViewModel> customerViewModel = (OpenSpreadsheetDocument(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, relativePath)));

    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, customerViewModel);
    return response;


}
```

Comment: 1) update app settings in app.config file of test to match web.config of the web project. 2) have action return `IHttpActionResult` abstraction which would allow for more flexibility when testing.

Comment: My angular application calls this web api to fetch IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel>. If I set it to return IHttpActionResult, how would my angular app work

Comment: the framework serialize it based on the type requested form client

Comment: you should also abstract the openxml to allow for mocking file access during unit testing

Comment: Hi Nksoki, I have updated my controller to return Httpresponse as per your suggestion. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) update app settings in `app.config` file of test to match `web.config` of the web project.

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="filePath" value="...." />
</appSettings>
```

2) have action return `IHttpActionResult` abstraction which would allow for more flexibility when testing.

```cs
public IHttpActionResult GetCustomer() {
    string relativePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath"];
    IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> customer = (OpenSpreadsheetDocument(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, relativePath)));
    return Ok(customer);
}
```

you should also abstract the openxml to allow for mocking file access during unit testing

```cs
public class CustomerController : ApiController {
    private readonly IExcelService service;

    public CustomerController(IExcelService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCustomer() {
        IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> customer = service.GetSpreadsheet();
        return Ok(customer);
    }    
}
```

Service contract could look like this

```cs
public interface IExcelService {
    IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> GetSpreadsheet();
}
```

with an implementation that has what originally had in your controller.

```
public class ExcelService : IExcelService {
    public IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> GetSpreadsheet() {
        string relativePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath"];
        IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> customer = (OpenSpreadsheetDocument(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, relativePath)));
        return customer;
    }
}
```

To Test lets make a fake service that is not dependent on path. (note: this could also be easily done with a mocking framework but for example purposes we'll use a fake)

```
public class FakeService : IExcelService {
    public IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> GetSpreadsheet() { 
        return new List<CustomerViewModel>() { new CustomerViewModel() };
    }
}
```

And now the test

```
[Test]
public void GetCustomerTest() {
    //Arrange
    var fakeService = new FakeService();
    var customerController = new CustomerController(fakeService) {
        Request = new HttpRequestMessage {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri(ServiceBaseURL + "api/getcustomer")
        }
    };
    customerController.Request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey, new HttpConfiguration());

    //Act    
    var _response = customerController.GetCustomer() as OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel>>;

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(_response);

    var responseResult = _response.Content;
    Assert.IsNotNull(responseResult);
    Assert.AreEqual(responseResult.Any(), true);    
}
```

Comment: I have added the same appsettings element in the app.config of the TestProject as per your suggestion .When I debug my unit test it, it looks for the path of the application root of the test project and dosent find it. There is something not right with the way path is read using path.combine. It searches for Appdata in its application path

Comment: That's because when unit testing it is under a completely different app domain than when running under IIS. Hence the reason for making the service a dependency that can the swapped out during unit testing.

Comment: If the openxml functionality is what you want to test then you'll have to make some changes to allow it to be a little more testable, which as it stands is outside of the scope of what you had originally asked for. The current changes allow you to test the controller response in isolation as well as decoupling the controller from implementation concerns which can be tested separately.

Comment: Thanks nkosi. Your inputs have been really helpful. I do want to mock as well and your suggestion is really helpful. But before I get to that i need to test the controller basic functionality which fails due to path problem. How do I solve that issue first

Comment: My suggestions are to allow for that basic functionality to be tested.

Comment: But when I implement that , as you said in your previous comment it is happening because when unit testing it is under a completely different app domain than when running under IIS.  How do I fix this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130352/discussion-between-tom-and-nkosi).